# Put a monitor on top my amp

Tags: amplifiers, studio

I'm currently making an home studio, I don't have all that much space and I want everything as efficient as possible. I was wondering that if i put my "sansui au 3900" in the middle of my desk and then put my monitor ( an ISP flat screen ) screen on top of it. If it will damage either the amplifier or my monitor. The amplifier still has enough space to breath (sort of speak). I tried looking on the internet but I can't really find much information about this particular dillemma and my dad doesn't know for sure either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not damage your amp or your monitor, however you may have interference if power or signal cables run too close to reach other.

Obviously you will want to keep all vents clear, as you mention, but there is nothing in either device that will damage the other.